# Транзакции php и методы

Tags: php, mysql, transaction

Ситуация - если в транзакции пишу insert into... то транзакция работает, если же создаю объект метода который делает insert into , то откат во время ошибки не происходит.

Так работает:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($db);     
try {
  insert into ...
  insert into ....
  .....
  mysqli_commit($db);
}catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  mysqli_rollback($db);
}
```

Так не работает:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($db);    
try {
  insertOne();
  insertSecond();
  .....
  mysqli_commit($db);
}catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  mysqli_rollback($db);
}
```

Во втором примере откат не происходит и вносится в базу , если в одном из инсертов есть ошибка. Можно ли что то сделать, чтоб в каждой транзакции не писать одни и теже insert а создавать объект метода?

Comment: похрде убедиться, что все ваши методы для выполнения запросов используют одно и то же подключение к базе данных (то есть, передают параметр `$db`

Comment: Ответ был очевиден. Как всё просто! Спасибо!